# New user notifications on Telegram app

Tags: ios

I keep getting notifications when a new user in my contacts joins telegram. Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Do you know how to disable notifications from iOS settings? Or is this more a question on how to configure that specific app? The former is easy to answer, the latter might be better off taken to the vendor support pages or more research done to avoid getting this closed as basic customer support. See [ask]

Comment: The former. How to disable it. I don't know how to, thus the question. I'd want to know how.

Answer (score 13):

There is an option to disable these notifications both on iOS and Android.

What we don't have now is an option to disable **new chat creation** for every new contact joined Telegram :(

iOS:
[image: iOS]

Android:
[image: Android]

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is: no!

No way to really disable Contact Joined notifications with Telegram in iOS.

But, if you prevent Telegram from having access to your contacts, it will stop the notifications, but it's not without side effects, like not knowing who sent you a message, so, I don't think it's a viable option.

Answer (score 3):

my answer is this is a bug.

Together, let's ask them to fix it 
I mentioned them on Twitter now please do the same or even better tell me if you know an official channel for such requests

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if any app doesn’t have granular settings to let you choose which notifications get sent, you can always stop them all.

- Open the settings app.
- Select notifications.
- Scroll down to the app in question and disable notifications.

If you need an app to have granular control of notifications, open a bug report with the vendor of the app or see if an alternate app can work with the service.

Developers and services can tell which accounts have stopped getting notifications so they can react before they lose you as a customer.

Answer (score 1):

you just can't do this. telegram have no option to disable new users joining notifications. all or nothing via general notifications settings.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Telegram Web

https://web.telegram.org

And bingo!  you won't be seeing these irritating user joined notifications :)

Comment: Not true, I use the web version, and the joined notification is there and I can't disable it!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://twitter.com/intent/like?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1241050320882393089%7Ctwgr%5E&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechweez.com%2F2020%2F03%2F24%2Fdisabling-the-contact-joined-telegram-setting-never-works-this-is-wh%2F&tweet_id=1241050320882393089) telegram says you need to delete your contacts and then you will not get any notifications for new users joining.

If you prefer to have your contacts synced then you could do what @PavelAlexeev suggested but the chats will still show on your feed, you just will not get a push notification for them. In this case I suggest you use Telegrams relatively new folder feature and that way your feed will not be cluttered.

I personally removed the syncing and I just add the contacts manually to Telegram when someone writes me there, and they called themselves @fdjsnvdljkv with no profile picture...